# Cygwin: Error while loading shared libraries when using c++ standard library

Tags: c++, cygwin, shared-libraries, std

Using i686-w64-mingw32-gcc on Cygwin64 I am facing an issue when trying to run an executable that uses a c++ standard library. Whenever I run the compiled executable an error is returned: *error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory*
Similar code in C runs fine:

C++:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    return(0);
}
```

C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("Hello World!");
    return(0);
}
```

I have run cygcheck but it does not return anything I can use. I must be missing something in my installation of Cygwin but I cannot seem to find it. Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Aren't you by any chance using `gcc` to compile C++ source code? In case if you do, you should use `g++` instead.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. Using gcc or g++ results in the same problem. I am using mingw32 for I need to later use threads and it seems to be only supported with this compiler on windows (excluding VS)

Comment: Cygwin doesn't set path for mingw dll. You can do it yourself according to your shell choice. Your comment about choosing mingw for threads doesn't entirely make sense.